# What is wrong with the following JDBC/MySQL query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

The following code excerpt fails to return anything in the ResultSet

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement   ("select images.id from images,testruns where images.test= ? and images.id=testruns.image_id");
ps.setString(1,value);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

However if I hardcode the images.test value to 1 as in

```
 "select images.id from images,testruns where images.test=1 and images.id=testruns.image_id"
```

I get the expected result of one row returned.

Any ideas as to how to resolve this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the data type of `value`?  And `images.test` is a what? And what is `value` set to?

Comment: +1 to Paul, as mentioned that is the main reason why your sql query do not work - query parameter type should reflect corresponding data type as it is stored in your db

Comment: hard coding ps.setInt(1,1); also works but when I try to use the String which is obtained from an html form it fails as in: PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement   ("select images.id from images,testruns where images.test=? and images.id=testruns.image_id");
           int number = Integer.parseInt(value);
           ps.setInt(1,number);
           ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

Comment: value is a String, images.test is an int and value is set to "1"

Comment: try debug/print the parsed number before setting there cannot be bug elsewhere if ps.setInt(1,1) works

Answer (score 5):

You are setting the query parameter as string, but the query indicates that it should really be an integer.

Answer (score 4):

Change code to

```
ps.setInt(1,value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use setString if your field is not a string.